using tokml to convert geojson to kml file in typescript
How do I use tokml library in typescript to convert a geojson to kml file.I get an error due to lack of types in the tokml library.I can't import tokml in my file.i get this error Could not find a declaration file for module 'tokml'. 'c:/Users/Window/Desktop/frontside/smala-admin-dashboard/node_modules/tokml/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. Try npm i --save-dev @types/tokmlif it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containingdeclare module 'tokml';ts(7016
If I try to install the types I get this error error Missing list of packages to add to your project.
